# Using Java GAE Datastore on Python locally

Tags: java, python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

How can I use my Java Datastore on Python version on Local, As Python environment has Inbuilt Interactive Console(for custom query), I want to use my application's Datastore which is currently running on GAE Java 1.8.2 to another version of GAE Python.

Comment: I'm not sure if that will work but dev_appserver.py has an argument --datastore_path which you can use to point to directory containing the datastore.

Answer (score 0):

--datastore_path=Location/datastore.db worked for me